# Get i18n to jquery fullcalendar in meteor

Tags: jquery, meteor, fullcalendar

Right now I try to get i18n to the jquery fullcalendar in meteor but this is more tricky as I thought. I think the following would do the job:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    lang: 'de'
});
```

I have put **lang: 'de'** in "Template.calendar.rendered" close where I set weekMode but I get no change. Do I need to load the translation first? I am asking since this code is placed at the jquery side:

```
<script src='fullcalendar/fullcalendar.js'></script>
<script src='fullcalendar/lang/es.js'></script>
```

> Thanks to Yaşar pointing it out: the above is a typo -> should be
>   de.js

If so where would I do this with meteor ? Or is this the false option to get the translation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use fullcalendar JQuery plugin meteor package.

```
meteor add rzymek:fullcalendar
```

Options to FullCalendar can be passed as attributes

**Template**

```
<template name="example">
    {{>fullcalendar options}}
</template>
```

**Js**

```
Template.example.helpers({
    options: function() {
        return {
            defaultView: 'basicWeek',
            lang: 'de'
        };
    }
});
```

or

```
{{> fullcalendar id="myCalendar" lang="de"}}
```

see here **this.data**  https://github.com/rzymek/meteor-fullcalendar/blob/master/template.js#L6

Package link https://atmospherejs.com/rzymek/fullcalendar

Example-demo: DE, EN http://stackoverflow-questions-29097104.meteor.com

Repo: https://github.com/yasaricli/stackoverflow-questions-29097104

Comment: I have tried the example but what ever I do I only get the English version. In .meteor/local/packages I have mrt:fullcalendar and I assume that the de.js file is not available -- so I may only need to put it in my project folder. Is this correct and if so .-- How would I do this?

Comment: **example demo** and **Repo** add reply.

Comment: @MBushveld  meteor version ?

Comment: $ meteor --version
Meteor 1.0.3.2

Comment: Why mrt:fullcalendar ? see https://github.com/yasaricli/stackoverflow-questions-29097104

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73204/discussion-between-mbushveld-and-yasar-cl).

Comment: The issues of getting the localisation to the fullcalendar is solved. Some other issues migration to the new package are open but not part of this question.